# Changing signature color to white in png picture in php

Tags: php

I am having user signature in png format. I want to change the color of the signature from black to white. I am using the following code

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('signature.png');
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 255, 255); // make it blue!
imagepng($image, 'signature.png');
```

But the background changed to black, I think because of using imagecreatefrompng how can i only change the color of signature.

Comment: HI Ricky, is it alpa channel on the png, or is it black from beginning?
could you provide us with the .png?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#106344) out? if it works

Answer (score 0):

i used this code it worked ....

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('signature.png');
$background = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $background);
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);

imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 255, 255); // make it blue!

imagepng($img, 'signature.png')
```